# How to resize image in imagemagick with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I have an image, the size of the image is 1920x1080, now I want to resize it to 1080x1920, but when I resize it, it returns to 1080x712

this is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mini_magick'
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("PathOfTheImage")
image.resize "1080x1920"
image.write "output.png"
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [ImageMagick syntax thing](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php). It's preserving aspect ratio instead of respecting your height argument.

Add a bang to force the dimensions image.resize "1080x1920"

```
image.resize "1080x1920!"
```

Comment: vote up the question sir so it might help the others.